# How to write an ArrayList to a text file?

Tags: c#

I have an ArrayList of strings and a text file called actors. I need to write all the elements in the ArrayList to a .txt file. Here is my code so far.

```
void WriteArrayList()
    {                        
        foreach (object actor in ActorArrayList)
        {
            File.WriteAllLines("C:\\actors.txt", actor); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you still using `ArrayList`? If you use `List<string>` your life will be much simpler.

Comment: And even if you do, don't name the object by it's type - `ActorArrayList`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really *must* use `ArrayList`, and assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, you can use the LINQ `Cast` method to convert it to a sequence of strings:

```
// .NET 4 and higher
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\actors.txt", ActorArrayList.Cast<string>());
```

For .NET 3.5, you need to convert it to an array as well:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\actors.txt", ActorArrayList.Cast<string>().ToArray());
```

(The `File.WriteAllLines` overload taking `IEnumerable<string>` was only introduced in .NET 4.)

Note how you don't need to loop over the list yourself - the point of `File.WriteAllLines` is that it does it for you.

If you're not even using .NET 3.5, you should loop yourself - the `foreach` loop can implicitly cast for you:

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"c:\actors.txt"))
{
    foreach (string actor in ActorArrayList)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(actor);
    }
}
```

If you can possibly use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`, you should. Generic collections were introduced in .NET 2, and since then there's been very little reason to use the non-generic collections.